# Is there any way to detect recent phone call duration in React native android

Tags: java, android, react-native, phone-call, android-phone-call

I am working with a calling app for which I need to detect call duration of recent phone call I just have made. So Is there any package or any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way or library which provide recent phone call duration but you can use [react-native-call-detection](https://github.com/priteshrnandgaonkar/react-native-call-detection#readme) which provide listeners of incoming call like

```
import CallDetectorManager from 'react-native-call-detection'

startListenerTapped() {
    this.callDetector = new CallDetectorManager((event, phoneNumber)=> {
    // For iOS event will be either "Connected",
    // "Disconnected","Dialing" and "Incoming"

    // For Android event will be either "Offhook",
    // "Disconnected", "Incoming" or "Missed"
    // phoneNumber should store caller/called number


    if (event === 'Disconnected') {
    // Do something call got disconnected
    }
    else if (event === 'Connected') {
    // Do something call got connected
    // This clause will only be executed for iOS
    }
    else if (event === 'Incoming') {
    // Do something call got incoming
    }
    else if (event === 'Dialing') {
    // Do something call got dialing
    // This clause will only be executed for iOS
    }
    else if (event === 'Offhook') {
    //Device call state: Off-hook.
    // At least one call exists that is dialing,
    // active, or on hold,
    // and no calls are ringing or waiting.
    // This clause will only be executed for Android
    }
    else if (event === 'Missed') {
        // Do something call got missed
        // This clause will only be executed for Android
  }
},
false, // if you want to read the phone number of the incoming call [ANDROID], otherwise false
()=>{}, // callback if your permission got denied [ANDROID] [only if you want to read incoming number] default: console.error
{
title: 'Phone State Permission',
message: 'This app needs access to your phone state in order to react and/or to adapt to incoming calls.'
} // a custom permission request message to explain to your user, why you need the permission [recommended] - this is the default one
)
}

stopListenerTapped() {
    this.callDetector && this.callDetector.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but this does not detect whether some one picked call or not . Every case  the 2 methods ;'offhook' and 'disconnected' executed sequentially but no one executed when some one pick phone